# How to understand the word 'care' in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Still, auditors did not mince words about the general state of care
>   during their review, which concluded near the end of the last school
>   year.

I think the sentence can be resolved into two parts:

1. auditors did not mince words about *something* during their review.
2. *something* which concluded near the end of the last school year.

So `the general state of care` means the conclusion of review? or the general state of concern? How to explain the word `care`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

general state of care = general state of concern

Simply put:

1. Auditors did not mince words about the general state of care during their review
2. The review concluded near the end of the last school year